# Fastlane upload_to_testflight lane is looking for target selection manually

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane, xcode13, fastfile

Im trying to build and upload an ipa file to testflight using Fastfile, but when i start fastlane command to run, there is pop is coming and that is looking for target selection. Hence it still needs a manual intervention however i aimed to automate the deployment process.

[Here it is the screenshot which im telling the actual issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh4n2.png)

I tried using SCHEME to pass TARGET of Xcode workspace , however it still requires to provide target selection manually.

Is there any way to automate the target selection for upload ipa file to Testflight?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the target from the parameters on the call:

```rb
version = get_version_number(
  xcodeproj: "Project.xcodeproj",
  target: "App"
)
```

The docs note the properties [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/get_version_number/).